# ms access form for allocating categories to a user

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2010

I am stuck with a little problem. I am using MS access 2003 (also 2010 on our server).

I have a table of users, a table of categories and a table for user_to_category.

How would I create a form which shows all the categories (with tick boxes) and as I click on each one, it adds that categoryID and userID (from session) to the user_to_category table.

I created individual checkboxes and used the onClick event, but I need to dynamically load the list of categories as people will add more and I don't want to manually add them.

Any ideas? I thought about using a listbox with the categories, then allowing a user to select multiple entries - this is then added to the table.. but not sure that's the best way?

thanks for any info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a continuous form with this query as its record source, and name the form *frmUsers*.

```
SELECT
    u.userID,
    u.user_name
FROM Users AS u
ORDER BY u.user_name;
```

Create a second form, *fsubUserCategories*, with this record source.

```
SELECT
    u2c.userID,
    u2c.categoryID,
    cat.category_name
FROM
    user_to_category AS u2c
    INNER JOIN Categories AS cat
    ON u2c.categoryID = cat.categoryID
ORDER BY cat.category_name;
```

Add a bound text box for category_name, and a combo box, *cboCategoryID*, bound to categoryID.  Use this query as as the combo's row source property.

```
SELECT
    cat.categoryID,
    cat.category_name
FROM
    Categories AS cat
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT categoryID
        FROM user_to_category
        WHERE userID=Forms!frmUsers!txtUserID
        ) AS sub
    ON cat.categoryID = sub.categoryID
WHERE (((sub.categoryID) Is Null))
ORDER BY cat.category_name;
```

Expand the footer section of frmUsers and add fsubUserCategories to a subform control in the footer.  Use userID as the link master/child properties on the subform control.

With that arrangement, the subform will display a row for each category assignment associated with the current user in the main form (frmUser).

Use frmUsers On Current event to requery the subform combo --- so it gets updated to contain only the available (unassigned) categories for the current user.

**Form_frmUsers**:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    ' Note: fsubUserCategories is the name of the subform control '
    ' my subform control uses the same name as the form it contains '
    ' but beware --- the names don't have to match --- double-check! '
    Me.fsubUserCategories.Form.cboCategoryID.Requery
End Sub
```

In fsubUserCategories, requery cboCategoryID from the After Delete Confirm, After Insert, and After Update events --- again so that it gets updated to contain only the unassigned categories available for the current user.

**Form_fsubUserCategories**:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
    Me.cboCategoryID.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Me.cboCategoryID.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboCategoryID.Requery
End Sub
```

This approach will allow you to view the category assignments for each user.  You can also add or delete rows from the subform to manage those assignments.

Comment: Thank you. I used this method to create the form which now works! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you're using MS Access, the easiest way to do this is to create a **continuous form** with the categories table as RecordSource.

You can check in the onClick event of the checkbox which category is the current one (= the one that was just clicked) by just putting a textbox with the categoryID on the form and checking the value of the textbox (it will always contain the ID of the currently clicked record).